# Laravel relations at runtime (workflow)

Tags: laravel, model

I'm looking for a solution to the following challenge:
Let's assume I have a model Customer and a model Order. Both are connected via a 1:n relationship. After a few orders, the customer's name changes. If I change the name in the customer now, all previous orders are also changed. My idea would now be to use an event to copy the customer's data into a second relation at runtime when saving the order in order to essentially freeze the data for the order. What is your workaround for this?

**Models / Relation before**

```php
<?php
// Customer
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}

<?php
// Order
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

**Models / Relation after**

```php
<?php
// Customer in workflow at runtime
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomerWrk extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }

    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
}
<?php
// Customer "base data"
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function customersWrk(){
        return $this->hasMany(CustomerWrk::class);
    }
}


<?php
// Order
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function customerWrk(){
        return $this->belongsTo(CustomerWrk::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many ways you can approach this and the first questions you should naturally ask are "should it matter if the name changed? It's still the same person" and "should I allow customers to change their names or should I just force them to make new accounts for big changes like these". If you still need this functionality then typically you'd have something like a `customers_history` table and copy the current customer record to that before updating it with new data. Then you can match the version of the customer record with the order based on create dates